# Tag merge request for [xmlparsing], [xml-parsing], and [xmlparser]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Each tags is used, respectively, in 66, 347 and 309 questions.

I think that remapping [xmlparsing](/questions/tagged/xmlparsing) and [xmlparser](/questions/tagged/xmlparser) to [xml-parsing](/questions/tagged/xml-parsing) should work.