# The tag [xml-parse] should be a synonym of [xml-parsing]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[xml-parse](/questions/tagged/xml-parse) is the same thing as [xml-parsing](/questions/tagged/xml-parsing). There are currently 31 questions under the former.

Same idea as [Tag merge request for [xmlparsing], [xml-parsing], and [xmlparser]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101175/tag-merge-request-for-xmlparsing-xml-parsing-and-xmlparser), really.

Comment: There are currently no questions under the former, thanks to @kiamlaluno =) They probably shouldn’t be synonymized, because [tag:xml-parse] is just plain wrong.

Comment: That was quick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed [xml-parse](/questions/tagged/xml-parse) and added [xml-parsing](/questions/tagged/xml-parsing) to those question that didn't use it. In fact, there were 8 questions that used both tags.

I would not make them synonyms for now. If in future [xml-parse](/questions/tagged/xml-parse) is re-created, then I would consider making it a synonym; that is if the tag is added to more questions than the questions from which it is removed.